# Changing diagonal of matrix using an if- statement?

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a matrix to replace every number along the diagonal (top left to bottom right), with -5. I have read previous questions and answers and I see that you can use... `np.fill_diagonal(A, -5)` to the get the answer. However I am trying to use a loop with if statements. Can anyone help me get started? Here is my matrix.

```
 A = array([[1.2,3.4,10.3],[2,8,78],[45,-36,8]])
```

Comment: What would you test with the `if` statement?

Comment: @heltonbiker -- I'm guessing OP wants to loop over each element in the matrix, test if `i == j` and if so, update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you want to iterate over columns and rows, so (quite silly, indeed):

```
for i in A.shape[0]:
    for j in A.shape[1]:
        if i == j:
            A[i,j] = -5
```

Although I have to think this is not needed if you ALREADY have an array/matrix, then using Mgilson's answer or, better yet, `numpy.fill_diagonal(array, value)`.

Comment: Don't use my answer.  Use **`np.fill_diagonal`**.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite easy.  Your matrix must be square, otherwise it doesn't really have a "diagonal".  The elements on the diagonal are `A[i,i]`, so you just need to loop over `for i in range(N)` and set `A[i,i] = -5` for each i.  (No if statements necessary)

Comment: @user1754710: The point is you don't need an `if` statement. If you really want to do it that way, use nested `for` loops and set the value to `-5` when `i == j`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `numpy`, but then your array has to be ofcourse a `numpy.array` or `numpy.matrix`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: A=np.random.random((3,3))
In [3]: A
Out[3]: 
array([[ 5.        ,  0.47884865,  0.8596375 ],
       [ 0.70925986,  5.        ,  0.29764543],
       [ 0.98049303,  0.13811067,  5.        ]])

In [4]: np.fill_diagonal(A, 5)

In [5]: A
Out[5]: 
array([[ 5.        ,  0.47884865,  0.8596375 ],
       [ 0.70925986,  5.        ,  0.29764543],
       [ 0.98049303,  0.13811067,  5.        ]])
```